# how to get edubuntu with GNOME 3.2 environment at the time of installing edubuntu

Tags: edubuntu

I have recently downloaded ISO file for Edubuntu but till now I have not installed it and I am using gnome now I just want to know that can I have GNOME environment in Edubuntu while installing it into my computer.

Comment: will the gnome interface as same as in gnome 3.2

Answer (score 1):

You must run

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-shell 
 sudo apt-get install gnome-session
```

Answer (score 0):

Edubuntu comes with **Unity v8** (same as the newest Ubuntu releases) as its default desktop environment. However if you wanna switch to GNOME you can always do that by:

**$sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop**

Comment: will switching to GNOME from unity be risky

Comment: Dude, Open Source comes with no warranty, so "NO-RISK" assurance nobody can give. As far as the changes are concerned you will loose your beautiful Dash.

Comment: you mean my workspaces of different desktops in a single monitor will be lost?

Comment: No I am taking about this [The unity dash](http://linuxconfig.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/oneric_unity_dash.jpg).

Comment: i am running gnome version not the unity